# Create new row after 3 item iterations with VueJS and Skeleton CSS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a row every time I do a v-for over 3 items of my array.

I'm also using Skeleton CSS.
Right now, the structure for only 3 items would look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="one-third column" v-for="item in items">
        <custom-component item="item"></custom-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I realize I should be doing the v-for over the row element and not on the column one, but how should I iterate? using `v-if="index % 3 === 0"`? That's just to validate if we are on the 3rd iteration.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: you could inspire from my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878624/render-closing-tag-conditionally-in-order-to-emulate-calendar-behavior) where i used computed property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this; Use `Math.ceil(items.length / 3)` to calculate the number of rows needed to hold the `items`, loop through rows, for each row loop through items for that row, i.e. `items.slice(3 * (rowIdx - 1), 3 * rowIdx)`.

```
<div class="row" v-for="rowIdx in Math.ceil(items.length / 3)">
    <div class="one-third column" v-for="item in items.slice(3 * (rowIdx - 1), 3 * rowIdx)">
        <custom-component :item="item"></custom-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! thanks, althought i had to remove the 3 * on both inside the slice.

Comment: I think that with this you will get out of range, the second for should look like this -  `item in items.slice(3*(rowIdx-1), 3*rowIdx)`. Am I right?

Comment: @DusanRadovanovic You are right. Just took a look, `v-for` with range starts with `1` instead of `0`

Comment: @msqar I think the issue you have is also related with the comment above. I didn't realize `v-for="i in n"` starts with `1`.

Comment: Oh gotcha, let me try!

Comment: @Psidom I'm checking that, if all of a sudden i got 8 items and not 9, the 3rd row won't be displayed. Any ideas on how to solve that? because this list will be dynamic. It might come 2, 3, 8, 15, 201 items... so it should show a row of 2 if the items.lenght is 8.

Comment: @msqar Are you doing something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/497523/ It seems to be working here.

Comment: @Psidom Oh lol! it works now, i had it like rowIdx * 3, dunno why but i changed it to 3 * rowIdx and it worked haha makes no sense, the order of a multiplication doesn't alter the result... but who knows. Thanks again man, it works perfect now.

Comment: you could inspire from my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878624/render-closing-tag-conditionally-in-order-to-emulate-calendar-behavior) where i used computed property