# Binding value doesn't update on change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties

I've been able to create values for different inputs, but if I make a change on the page it shows correctly in the form, but when I use developer tools and check if the change is updated there, it doesn't update. I've tried various ways to v-bind:value or v-model but it doesn't react. I'd like for it to be able to react so that I don't have to go to each input and grab the updated value, I could just call the array that was created with the updated values. Not sure what I'm missing.

http://jsfiddle.net/fjLvhutp/

```
 <ul>
      <li v-for="item in finditem()" v-if="item.html == 0">
          <label v-bind:for="item.item">{{ item.item }}</label>
          <div v-bind:id="item.item">{{ item.result }}</div>
      </li>
      <li v-else-if="item.html == 1">
          <label v-bind:for="item.item">{{ item.item }}</label>
          <input type="text"v-model="item.result" />$
      </li>
      <li v-else-if="item.html == 2">
          <label v-bind:for="item.item">{{ item.item }}</label>
          <input type="checkbox" v-bind:id="item.item" v-bind:id="item.item" v-bind:value="item.result" />
      </li>
      <li v-else-if="item.html == 3">
          <label v-bind:for="item.item">{{ item.item }}</label>
          <select v-bind:id="item.item">
               <option v-for="drop in item.dropdown">{{ drop.Value }}</option>
          </select>
      </li>
 </ul>

 var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#components-demo',
    data: {
        todos: [
            newData
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        finditem() {
            var setarray = [];
            var result = Object.keys(newData).map(function (key) {
                return [key, newData[key]];
            });
            var travelModeId = '';
            $(result).each(function (i, value) {
                var getValue = value[0];

                // No Input
                if (getValue == "Reservation" || getValue == "LastUpdatedBy" || getValue == "LastUpdated") {
                    var first = value[0];
                    var second = value[1];
                    var htmlId = 0;
                    setarray.push({ item: first, result: second, html: htmlId });
                }
                // Text Input
                if (getValue == "Fare" || getValue == "AgentFee" || getValue == "ChangeFee" || getValue == "NteAmount" || getValue == "GsaRate" || getValue == "ClientApprovedAmount" || getValue == "CancelledDate") {
                    var first = value[0];
                    var second = value[1];
                    var htmlId = 1;
                    setarray.push({ item: first, result: second, html: htmlId });
                }
                // Checkbox
                if (getValue == "Ground" || getValue == "NoGsa") {
                    var first = value[0];
                    var second = value[1];
                    var htmlId = 2;
                    setarray.push({ item: first, result: second, html: htmlId });
                }
                // Select
                if (getValue == "TravelModeId") {
                    travelModeId = value[1];
                }
                // Select Dropdown
                if (getValue == "TravelModeDropdown") {
                    var first = "Travel Mode";
                    var second = value[1];
                    var htmlId = 3;
                    setarray.push({ item: first, result: travelModeId, html: htmlId, dropdown: second });
                }
            });
            return setarray;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please provide a running code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52879589/8172857) or a fiddle in order to debug it easily

Comment: updated with a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Data should be a function which returns an object and not just an object like:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      todos: [
          newData
      ]
    }
}
```

Also `finditem()` should be a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) like:

```
computed: {
    finditem: function() {
        var setarray = [];
        var result = Object.keys(newData).map(function (key) {
            return [key, newData[key]];
        });
        var travelModeId = '';
        $(result).each(function (i, value) {
            var getValue = value[0];

            // No Input
            if (getValue == "Reservation" || getValue == "LastUpdatedBy" || getValue == "LastUpdated") {
                var first = value[0];
                var second = value[1];
                var htmlId = 0;
                setarray.push({ item: first, result: second, html: htmlId });
            }
            // Text Input
            if (getValue == "Fare" || getValue == "AgentFee" || getValue == "ChangeFee" || getValue == "NteAmount" || getValue == "GsaRate" || getValue == "ClientApprovedAmount" || getValue == "CancelledDate") {
                var first = value[0];
                var second = value[1];
                var htmlId = 1;
                setarray.push({ item: first, result: second, html: htmlId });
            }
            // Checkbox
            if (getValue == "Ground" || getValue == "NoGsa") {
                var first = value[0];
                var second = value[1];
                var htmlId = 2;
                setarray.push({ item: first, result: second, html: htmlId });
            }
            // Select
            if (getValue == "TravelModeId") {
                travelModeId = value[1];
            }
            // Select Dropdown
            if (getValue == "TravelModeDropdown") {
                var first = "Travel Mode";
                var second = value[1];
                var htmlId = 3;
                setarray.push({ item: first, result: travelModeId, html: htmlId, dropdown: second });
            }
        });
        return setarray;
    }
}
```

And than you call the computed property like:

```
 <li v-for="item in finditem" v-if="item.html == 0">
```

Methods don't get called again automatically if you variable/dependency is changed which gets used inside the method.
Computed porperty get called again if a variable/dependency is changed and so `v-for` gets the correct data automatically.
So try these changes and let's see if it updates the data.

Comment: didn't update the value, now i see a computed property in developer tools now though with an array of the properties

Comment: Are your updated values now inside of this computed property?

Comment: no only the initial values, when i add new values in the form, it doesn't translate to the developer tools so i know its not updating right still

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues here:

1. `item` is not within `v-for`, rather `li` elements are siblings to the first with the loop. Merge all `li` elements together and use the `v-if` and `v-if-else` conditionals on the inputs instead.
2. `data` is an object and not a function.
3. No `key` attribute on `li`.

**template**

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(item, index) in finditem()" :key="index">
    <label :for="item.item">{{ item.item }}</label>
    <div v-if="item.html === 0" :id="item.item">{{ item.result }}</div>
    <input v-else-if="item.html == 1" :id="item.item" type="text" v-model="item.result" />$
    <input v-else-if="item.html == 2" type="checkbox" :id="item.item" v-model="item.result" />
    <select v-else-if="item.html == 3" :id="item.item" v-model="item.result">
       <option v-for="drop in item.dropdown" :value="drop.Value" :key="drop.Value">{{ drop.Value }}</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**script**

```
data: () => ({
  todos: []
})
```

**Update**

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/digitaldrifter/fjLvhutp/47/).  The inputs now render based on the conditional statements in the template and removed the jQuery dependency.

Comment: hmm doing it this way doesn't return any values in the developer tools, just an empty array

Comment: Where is `newData` coming in from?

Comment: its a separate variable var newData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

Comment: I added newData in the todos array and everything seems to work ( because there are no errors ) but its just not updating in developer tools for some reason, its showing like: data > todos Array[1] > 0: Object > then all the data

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things that can cause this issue:

1. Its good practice to create your `data` as a function.
2. The reference of your variable `newdata` within your `finditem()` method should be `this.todos[0]` or but shouldn't you use `this.todos` as an empty array?. This is because `newData` is a variable or string or number or whatever?

Your code should look something like (thinking `newData` is a string within the todos array):

```
new Vue({
    el: '#components-demo',
    data: function () {
        return {
            todos: ['newData']
        }
    },
    methods: {
        finditem() {
            var setarray = [];
            var result = Object.keys(this.todos).map(function (key) {
                return [key, this.todos[key]];
            });
            var travelModeId = '';
            $(result).each(function (i, value) {
                var getValue = value[0];

                // No Input
                if (getValue == "Reservation" || getValue == "LastUpdatedBy" || getValue == "LastUpdated") {
                    var first = value[0];
                    var second = value[1];
                    var htmlId = 0;
                    setarray.push({ item: first, result: second, html: htmlId });
                }
                // Text Input
                if (getValue == "Fare" || getValue == "AgentFee" || getValue == "ChangeFee" || getValue == "NteAmount" || getValue == "GsaRate" || getValue == "ClientApprovedAmount" || getValue == "CancelledDate") {
                    var first = value[0];
                    var second = value[1];
                    var htmlId = 1;
                    setarray.push({ item: first, result: second, html: htmlId });
                }
                // Checkbox
                if (getValue == "Ground" || getValue == "NoGsa") {
                    var first = value[0];
                    var second = value[1];
                    var htmlId = 2;
                    setarray.push({ item: first, result: second, html: htmlId });
                }
                // Select
                if (getValue == "TravelModeId") {
                    travelModeId = value[1];
                }
                // Select Dropdown
                if (getValue == "TravelModeDropdown") {
                    var first = "Travel Mode";
                    var second = value[1];
                    var htmlId = 3;
                    setarray.push({ item: first, result: travelModeId, html: htmlId, dropdown: second });
                }
            });
            return setarray;
        }
    }
});
```

> Nope, I did not test this code...