# Vue.js print raw html and call component methods

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am dynamically loading the html content from an ajax request. This html has some buttons like

```
<button @click="someComponentMethod">Add</button>
```

As you can see I am trying to call components methods. But Its not working.

I think instead of @click html's default attribute "onclick" should work. But this will only recognize the function that are defined in global scope. Can someone guide me how I can call component's function from core javascript i.e using "onclick".

**Update**

Ok! I got it that v-html will not compile that html. But can you guys tell me how can I call component method from javascript (i.e outside of component scope). In this way I will be able to use `onclick="JAVASCRIPT_CODE_TO_EXECUTE_METHOD"`.

Comment: how you add the html content?, please put this code. Thanks

Comment: I am using v-for to traverse the data and then v-html to print the html

Comment: read here, v-html only add html not compile.https://stackoverflow.com/a/45494778/4921471

Comment: @AmarjitSingh check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54095283/8172857)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loading html I end up saving component in JSON format. This component has a template property that stores the html string. In this way I am able to store and load component to and from database and it works without any issue.

Answer (score 4):

That content will not be compiled as mentioned in [`official docs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52879589/8172857) :

> The contents of the `span` will be replaced with the value of the `rawHtml` property, interpreted as plain HTML - data bindings are ignored. Note that you cannot use `v-html` to compose template partials, because `Vue` is not a string-based templating engine. Instead, components are preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and composition.