# How to pass vuejs for-loop index value as the parameter of HTML button onclick javascript function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
<div v-for="(grp,idx) in vm">
    <button onclick="addPlant(idx)">
    .......
    </button>
</div>
```

**addPlant()** is a *javascript* function and not a VueJS method.

How can I pass the `idx` value to the javascript method now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reference the Vue template variables from a vanilla javascript `onclick` handler like you're trying to do.

You should pass the index value to a Vue `@click` handler and call the vanilla javascript method from there:

```js
function addPlant(idx) {
  alert(idx)
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { 
      groups: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onButtonClick(idx) {
      addPlant(idx)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(grp, idx) in groups">
    <button @click="onButtonClick(idx)">
      {{ idx }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If we go to be limited to your specific use case we could assign `index` to `data-label`  attribute *(which is bound to `index`)* and pass `this.getAttribute('data-label')` as parameter, `this` refers to the Html element not to the Vue instance or component:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return{
      bars:['a','b','c']
    }
  }
  
})

function addPlant(index){
  console.log("# "+index)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
 <div v-for="(bar,idx) in bars">
    <button :data-label="idx" onclick="addPlant(this.getAttribute('data-label'))">
{{bar}}
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Vue method calling the javascript function

```
methods: {
  callAddPlant: function(idx) {
    addPlant(idx)
  }
}
```

...

```
<div v-for="(grp,idx) in vm">
    <button v-on:click="callAddPlant(idx)">
       .......
    </button>
</div>
```