# Replace Component template Dynamically in Angular2/4+

Tags: javascript, angular, templates, vue.js, components

is there any way to replace the component template in angular4+ or use **vue**'s `v-html`,somehow to render html getting from server including javascript.
I have used `v-html` it renders my html but not compiling javascript.

Comment: please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090325/vue-js-print-raw-html-and-call-component-methods/54091030#54091030)

Comment: Thanks for that @BoussadjraBrahim but this does not solve my problem.