# How to create button from data section in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm working with vuejs and want to create a clickable button which declared in data section. How can I do that?

```html
<template>
    {{my_btn}}
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                my_btn: '<button class="btn btn-indigo outline" @click="sayhello">VISIT OUR WEBSITE</button>'
            }
        },
         methods: {
           sayhello(){
              alert('hello');
           }
         }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090325/vue-js-print-raw-html-and-call-component-methods/54091030#54091030

Answer (score 3):

This is how to create a button inside the `data` method
but to display it as an HTML not string you'll need to add it inside the [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) attribute.
Note: that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates, so you should add event listener inside  `mounted` Lifecycle.
note: I add `id` to your text so i'll be able to get the element and add an event listener

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-html="my_btn"></span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      my_btn:
        '<button id="btn" class="btn btn-indigo outline">VISIT OUR WEBSITE </button>'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sayhello() {
      alert("hello");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", this.sayhello)

  }
};
</script>
```

in the end, you can do it with the `vue` way to avoid the risk of rendering arbitrary HTML on your website because it can be very dangerous it can easily lead to `XSS attacks`.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-indigo outline" @click="sayhello">VISIT OUR WEBSITE
        </button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
               
            }
        },
         methods: {
           sayhello(){
              alert('hello');
           }
         }
    }
</script>
```

I hope you find it usfull

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful