# How to transfer part of an array to a new line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Good afternoon, please tell me, I have an array consisting of numbers, how can I make the part of the array that stands after the number before each unit be transferred to a new line?

My App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="mounth">{{ mounthDays }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
        mounthDays: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
      for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        this.mounthDays.push(i)
      }
    }
    if(this.mounthDays[123] === 31){
      this.mounthDays.splice(59, 3)
      this.mounthDays.splice(120, 1)
      this.mounthDays.splice(181, 1)
      this.mounthDays.splice(273, 1)
      this.mounthDays.splice(334, 1)



    }
    console.log(this.mounthDays)

    }
  }
</script>
```

[image]

[image: That's how I want my array to look]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Can you show the desired output?

Comment: Now I will add a screen to my question and explain how I want it to be

Comment: Now my array looks like this, I want the rest of the array to move to a new line after the digit before the one.

Comment: To me, It is really unclear what you are asking. Can you rephrase your question or show an example of the result you want to achieve?

Comment: for example, you see the number 28 in the second row, and after it stands 1. Here I want the blank line after the 28, and the rest of the array is transferred to the new line

Comment: It will be normal if I write in the Word how I want my array to look?

Comment: i think you want to create a calendar, try to check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878624/render-closing-tag-conditionally-in-order-to-emulate-calendar-behavior)

Comment: @AndreyBelichenko taking an array to a new line? It is unclear what you want?

Comment: I added a screenshot of how I want my array to look

Comment: You've added images but which of them shows the desired result? Please give each a title.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an array of all numbers, make it array of arrays and then print it on separate lines. Something like this should work:

```
var monthsWithDays = [];

for (var x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
    var days = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        days.push(i)
    }

    monthsWithDays.push(days);
}

monthsWithDays.forEach(daysArray => console.log(daysArray));
```

If you want just a string with newlines, then something like this should work:

```
monthsWithDays.map(daysArray => daysArray.join(",")).join("\n")
```

EDIT:
I now see what you are trying to do with your `splice` stuff. I don't think you have a right approach here. But the code above could be fixed to do this:

```
function daysInMonth (month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

var monthsWithDays = [];

for (var x = 1; x <= 12; x++) {
    var days = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= daysInMonth(x, 2019) ; i++) {
        days.push(i)
    }

    monthsWithDays.push(days);
}

monthsWithDays.map(daysArray => daysArray.join(",")).join("\n")
```

I borrowed the `daysInMonth` function from [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184334/get-number-days-in-a-specified-month-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example for the current year, which uses a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) and some [date math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184334):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(month, index) in monthsAndDays" :key="index">{{ month }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184334
const daysInMonth = (month, year) => new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

// [1..n]
const oneToN = n => Array.from(Array(n), (_, i) => i + 1);

export default {
  computed: {
    monthsAndDays() {
      const year = new Date().getFullYear();
      return oneToN(12).map(i => oneToN(daysInMonth(i, year)));
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Lol, I just cited the same daysInMonth question